# Active Directory Federation for multi tenant application

Tags: azure, multitenancy, active-directory

For AD Federation in a multi-tenant environment-
My research so far with Azure, tells me that the onpremise AD needs to be integrated with the cloud AD.

1. Are there any cons/ security concerns with this model keeping multi-tenancy in mind?
2. What other options do I have?

Comment: You could also create an STS that can redirect the users to the onprmise on the tenant identification. This doesn't require you to sink up with azure AD